# JPA using Hibernate doesn't query exact strings on MySQL 8

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using JPA 2.2 with Hibernate 5.4 to work with a underlying MySQL 8 database.

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
final Root<Person> root = getCriteriaBuilder.from(Person.class);
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), "Doe");
// request resultset here
```

The given code should query a persons name, which is exactly "Doe", but it finds also "DOE" and "doE", in other words, query is not case sensitive executed.
I also tried

```
criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "Doe");
```

but this doesn't work either.
My assumption is, that SQL should use =-operator, but I can find only "LIKE" inside WHERE-clause.

Is there a bug or is something else not working?

Comment: Check your DB collation (there are both case sensitive and case insensitive collations).

Comment: What minus said. You have to use `*_bin` or `*_cs` collations. If you are using `*_ci` collations, your queries will be `c`ase `i`insensitive

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, collation (never heard before) was the problem. Now its working.